# node webpack hangs. How to debug?

Tags: docker, webpack, babeljs, orocrm

I am trying to build ORO Platform js assets, using a non-docker environment, it works like a charm, but in Docker (either during Docker Build, or container execution)  the building process stop and hangs with 100% CPU.

```
67% [0] building 1416/1470 modules 54 active ... ndles/orotask/sidebar_widgets/assigned_tasks/css/styles.scss
```

The building process does not necessarily hang on the exact same file. And also, the build seems to succeed on some occasion.

I've try to reduce to a minimum the process by removing `Happy`, tested with `--max-old-space-size=4096`, but no luck.

Sources : https://github.com/oroinc/platform/tree/master/build

How would you recommend debugging this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a known issue when a NodeJs process hangs while you run it from the `root` user. As I know, there is no workaround for now. Consider using another user to build the assets.

If it's not the case, please review [the Troubleshooting section in OroAssetBundle](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/bundles/platform/AssetBundle/#troubleshooting), that might help.

Comment: Wow!  It was indeed because `node` was running as `root`.  Thanks a lot !